# How to select nodes where node name contains "mystring"

Tags: c#, xpath, c#-2.0, xmldocument

I need to get XmlNodeList where node name contains "mystring"

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <node1>
    node1 value
  </node1>
  <node2_mystring>
    node2 value
  </node2_mystring>
  <node3>
    node3 value
  </node3>
  <node4_mystring>
    node 4 value
  </node4_mystring>
</root>
```

Desired output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <node2_mystring>
    node2 value
  </node2_mystring>
  <node4_mystring>
    node 4 value
  </node4_mystring>
</root>
```

I tried something like `XmlNodeList mystringElements = xmlDocument.SelectNodes(@"//*[contains(name,'mystring')]");`

But it returns zero node. What should I put in XPath query to achieve this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use the [`name()`](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_functions.asp#node) function. Just `name` alone will try to match an element named "name".

You want this:

```
//*[contains(name(),'mystring')]
```